# How to automate login to Microsoft Account Python

Tags: python, authentication, automation

I want to scrap some info from my MS account webpage, but I need to log in first to this page: https://login.live.com/login.srf.
I want to write simple script in Python, using requests or urllib2 (does not matter which one).
When I'm doing it from a webbrowser, it first asks for login (email) and then window(field) with password appears. I'm little new to this stuff, so I'm not sure if I have to use two requests (post?).

Comment: May be imap is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Since it uses javascript for the authentication, you cannot use requests and urllib modules. You should use Selenium. Read the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) and research a bit. If you come across new errors, feel free to start a new question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer, in selenium it works, but i was thinking of ommiting using webbrowser itself. But if its not possible i will probably stick with selenium.

Comment: unfortunately, requests, despite being powerful has no ability to run javascripts because you need a physical interface for the API to interact with it. The webdriver in Selenium acts as this interface. You can try using PhantomJS which is a headless browser driver that is faster than Selenium and has JS support but most probably, it will be blocked by Microsoft because it doesn't provide the headers for verification.