# Web scraping with python from a website that uses microsoft login

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, cookies

It's been 6 hours that I have been trying to extract the grades from my school website.
My code is working perfectly, I have just a problem...
I cannot get connected through the Microsoft login page.
The only way to get connected is by getting my cookies and pasting them into the code.
This is not what I want. I want to put my email and my password and get connected.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

'''
publishedGrade[x]
    1 = ID
    3 = grade
'''

cookies = {
    'SERVERID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'JSESSIONID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
}

# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Create the payload
payload = {'loginfmt':'XXXXXXXX', 
          'passwd':'XXXXXXXX'
         }

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/08983daf-5aca-4f44-bc65-c23ce32d46ec/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=dcd45342-6b22-4490-aaa6-39e6199c2bf6&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faurion.ieseg.fr%2Fopenid_connect_login&nonce=XXXXXX&state=XXXXXXXX&sso_reload=true", data=payload, cookies=cookies)

# Navigate to the next page and scrape the data
soup = session.get('https://aurion.ieseg.fr/faces/LearnerNotationListPage.xhtml', cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id="form:dataTableFavori_data")
elements = results.find_all("tr", role="row")

allIDs=[]
allGrades=[]

#Getting each published grade
for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    publishedGrade = element.find_all("td", role="gridcell")

    #Extracting only the course name
    ID=publishedGrade[1].text.split("_")

    #Appending course ID and the grade
    #Extractin the digit ID
    #example XXX_XXX_XXX_ID_XXX
    allIDs.append(ID[len(ID)-2])   
    allGrades.append(publishedGrade[3].text)

#Saving all in a CSV file
with open('text.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for w in range(len(elements)):
            writer.writerow([allIDs[w], allGrades[w]])
```

In this code I just censored cookies password email and the end of the url of the microsoft login page.

I tried to use Selenium, but it is not optimal. Because I plan to integrate the code in an html page with Django.

I extracted the html page showed when I tried to get connected with my email. When I try to show it in a browser page, it redirects me to https://login.microsoftonline.com/cookiesdisabled.

[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8PUZ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013348/how-to-automate-login-to-microsoft-account-python same answer as this didn't check deeper but they usually have multiple requests and some security measures so i suggest using selenium or playwright to do the login

Comment: Thank you I will look this. Can I use selenium with django or flask ?
Because we need a webdriver etc.

Comment: After looking at the post, it seems that "requests" is not working because it uses javascript for the authentication.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Up; Nobody has an idea ?